# Return Closest Dates either side of Specific Date Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to calculate some constant maturity Implied Vols for options and am a bit stuck when trying to get my program to automatically chose which expiries to use for the calculations.

The problem is rather simple. Let's say I have a list of dates:

```
dates = ['2019-12-20', '2019-12-27', '2020-01-31', '2020-03-26']
```

What I'd like to do is give the program a number of days in the future from today, let's use 30 in this case, and have it return to me the two dates either side of this number. In this case it would return `'2019-12-27'` and `'2020-01-31'`.

Unfortunately I can't give any attempted code as I really don't know where to begin here. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
# if dates is not a pandas series
dates = pd.Series(dates)

dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)

today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())
future = today + pd.to_timedelta('30D')

dates.where(dates>future).min(), dates.where(dates<=future).max()
```

Output:

```
(Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-12-27 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the answer, I think I will use this and put it in a function as it's nice and simple. One last question though. How can I convert the output of say `Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00')` to a string? I need the dates as strings as the API I use to download the options data needs it in string format. Thanks again

Comment: And sorry I also just need the date as a string, not the hours/minutes etc

Comment: `dates.where(dates>future).min().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datetime package:

```
import datetime

dates = ['2019-12-20', '2019-12-27', '2020-01-31', '2020-03-26']

dates_list = []
for date in dates:
    dates_list.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
x= datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(30)

smaller = -9999
bigger = 9999

for date in dates_list:
    delta = date-x
    if delta.days <0 and delta.days>smaller:
        date_before = date
        smaller = delta.days
    if delta.days >0 and delta.days<bigger:
        date_after = date
        bigger = delta.days
print(date_before, date_after)
```